# How validate unique email out of the user that is updating it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, email, authentication

I am using Laravel 5.2 and want to update user's account using validator.

I want to keep email field unique, but, if the user type his current email it will break. How can I update if the email is unique, except the user's own current email?

Comment: Only validate the email field if it's different? Something like... `if ($user->email != $request->email)`.  Clearly there should be some differences in checks between adding a user and updating a user.

Comment: No, I want to validate if it is unique. But I want to allow the user update his email to his CURRENT email without fail in the validation unique.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can tell that to validators:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id
```

Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique), in section 'Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID'.

Comment: Just an FYI, this worked great in the 5.6.33 version.

`'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,`

Comment: not working in laravel 7.2

Answer (score 44):

In Request Class you will probably need this validation in PUT or PATCH method where you don't have user then you can simply use this rule

```
 You have 2 options to do this
```

1:

```
 'email' => "unique:users,email,$this->id,id"
```

OR

2:

```
 use Illuminate\Validation\Rule; //import Rule class 
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id); //use it in PUT or PATCH method
```

**$this->id** 
is providing id of the user because **$this** is object of Request Class and Request also contains user object.

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required'
            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => "unique:users,email,$this->id,id",
                                   OR
                //below way will only work in Laravel ^5.5 
                'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id),

               //Sometimes you dont have id in $this object
               //then you can use route method to get object of model 
               //and then get the id or slug whatever you want like below:

              'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->route()->user->id),
            ];
        }
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Hope it will solve the problem while using request class.

Answer (score 9):

On Laravel 5.7+ to instruct the validator to ignore the user's ID, we'll use the Rule class to fluently define the rule. In this example, we'll also specify the validation rules as an array instead of using the | character to delimit the rules:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => ['required',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
]);
```

Comment: This will only work for the current logged in user. If the user who is editing the user is for example an admin this solution will not work. You however can get the user ID from the route (if available) $this->route('id') or $this->route('user') when using resource routes.

Comment: Exactly the `$user` variable is a representation of the user email you want to ignore, it can be the `auth()->user()` or a `request('user_id')` depending on your project.

Answer (score 9):

For coders using `FormRequest` & Laravel 5.7 and facing this problem, you can do something like this

```
public function rules() {

    return [
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user),
        ],
    ];

}
```

The `$this->user` will return the user ID coming from the request.

Answer (score 8):

there's many methods :

**1- In controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
  $request->validate([
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
  ]);
}
```

**2-Form requests**

Form requests are custom request classes that contain validation logic. Read more here.

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->user->id,
  ];
}
```

Comment: I'm upgrading my app from 5.1 to latest version, and I'm currently on 5.4 when my old way (`$this->get('id)`) broke. Your solution worked! In the docs it doesn't mention this.

Answer (score 7):

```php
'email' => "required|email|unique:users,email,$id",
```

In a **laravel 8**. I also search for long time. this will work

Comment: it will be useful for others to quickly grasp your solution if you add a bit of formatting to the code and also describe what you have done or add references.

Comment: Best answer! Most elegant and works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

In laravel 9, you can do something like this In your Request file:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id)
        ];
    }
```

Check Laravel documentation for unique validation:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 2):

Creat form request and add this code on App/Http/Request/YourFormRequest class

```
public function rules()
{  // get user by uri segment
   $user = User::find((int) request()->segment(2)); 
   return [ 
        'name' => 'required|string|max:100', 
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$user->id.',id' 
    ];
}
```

check the doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests)

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_user  = Users::where('access_token', $request->access_token)->first();

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
    'name'            => 'required|max:255',
    "email"           => "required|email|max:100|unique:users,email,".$current_user->id.",id",  
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel 7 to build an API, if you want something clean, you can simply use :

```
public function rules()
{
    $emailRule = Rule::unique((new User)->getTable());

    if (request()->isMethod('put')) {
        // we update user, let's ignore its own email
        // consider your route like : PUT /users/{user}
        $emailRule->ignore($this->route('user'));
    }

    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'email',
            $emailRule
        ],
    ];
}
```

You can get the user you want to update (using `PUT` method here) and ignore him.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update user's account you can create a class AccountRequest that extends [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AccountRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'email' => [auth()->id() == 1 ? 'sometimes' : 'required', 'email', Rule::unique((new User)->getTable())->ignore(auth()->id())]
        ];
    }
}
```

Then, in your AccountController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Gate;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Requests\AccountRequest;

class AccountControllerextends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the account.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function edit()
    {
        return view('account.edit');
    }

    /**
     * Update the account
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\AccountRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function update(AccountRequest  $request)
    {

        auth()->user()->update(['name' => $request->get('name'),
                                'email' => $request->get('email')]);

        return back()->withStatus(__('Account successfully updated.'));
    }
}
```

and your routes would look like this

```
Route::get('account', ['as' => 'account.edit', 'uses' => 'AccountController@edit']);
Route::put('account', ['as' => 'account.update', 'uses' => 'AccountController@update']);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if($request->ID){
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name'      => 'required',
                'mobile'    => 'required|unique:schools,mobile,'.$request->ID,
                'email'     => 'required|unique:schools,email,'.$request->ID,
                'address'   => 'required',
            ]);
        }
        else{
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name'      => 'required',
                'mobile'    => 'required|unique:schools',
                'email'     => 'required|unique:schools',
                'address'   => 'required',
            ]);
        }
```