# How to make conditions on laravel form request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question,

I have a Controller and I Have a form request to validate the update.

I want to make conditions for example. If I update an "name" the form request allow change the name but if I didn't make change use the same and don't appear "unique rule" because sometimes I have to change the name, but some times not and the problem is when I haven't to change the name because if I put the same name, I have the message "duplicated" and if I try to update another ID appear "duplicated".

I don't know if you understand but i am trying to be specific.

My rule is the next with a condition.

```
    public function rules()
{
        if  (Attribute::where('name', '=', Request::get('name'))->count() == 1) {
            return [
                'name' => 'required'
            ];
        } elseif (Attribute::where('name', '=', Request::get('name'))->count() != 1) {
            return [
                'name' => 'unique:attributes'
            ];
        }
    }
```

So I compare if name count is ==1 only required but when is !=1 only unique but doesn't work correctly.

Some suggestion?

Comment: Just make name as unique while insert and remove unique rule when you update the details

Comment: I have a rule on another RequestForm for unique on insert but the user can update the name but doesn't take some name used and if he didnt update the name can insert without the message "duplicated"

Comment: Which laravel version used ?

Comment: i am using the version 5.5

Comment: @FMoreira I've added my answer, please have a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on this Answer,

[How validate unique email out of the user that is updating it in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942367/how-validate-unique-email-out-of-the-user-that-is-updating-it-in-laravel)

You can ignore the current user details and preserve the unique rule while validating the update request in such rule,

As per documentation,

**Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:**

> Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check. For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address. You only want to throw a validation error if the user provides an e-mail address that is already used by a different user. To tell the unique rule to ignore the user's ID, you may pass the ID as the third parameter:

Your rule while updating should look like,

```
'name' => 'unique:attributes,name,'.$attribute->id
```

Here, `$attribute` refers to the attribute being updated.

I hope you will understand.

Comment: This solution Work perfect but how to i catch o prevent that the user modify another "id" and put the same name. On the another "id" i think that have to appear "duplicated" first i have to make a condition (i think so) to prevent that another use use the same name using the id and the name may be

Comment: @FMoreira How did you give id in the form request ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation) to check unique

```
 use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

 Rule::unique('table_name')->ignore('id');
```

Comment: This solution Work perfect and is really easy but how to i catch o prevent that the user modify another "id" and put the same name. On the another "id" i think that have to appear "duplicated" first i have to make a condition (i think so) to prevent that another use use the same name using the id and the name may be

Comment: while you updating record then you have to send id in request, so that you can put in ignore.

Comment: i think that you dont understand. I can ignore name correctly but if i change the id (example attributes/1?name=123123&cat_id=1 for attributes/2?name=123123&cat_id=1 ) at the second example have to appear like the name exist (duplicated) but if i ignore only work if i dont update the name on the first case

Comment: field_name'  =>  'sometimes|unique:table_name,field_name,ignore_id', have you validate like this ?

Comment: 'name' => ['required',Rule::unique('categories')->ignore($this->name)] like this

Comment: its wrong dear, instead of $this->name use $this->id, if you dont have $this->id while inserting set it as zero(0).

Comment: i continue thinking that dont understand. I want to update without change the name only in one id and with the line Work but if i change (i use postman) the id of 1 to 2 i can use duplicated name .