# Laravel validate unique mobile out of the user that is updating it on API level?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

as [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40942367/1830228) couldn't help me i'm wondering how can i validate unique mobile out of the user that is updating it on API level. for example:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $user = User::whereMobileNumber($request->mobile_number)->first();

        /*VALIDATION IF USER NOT FOUND*/
        if ($user == null) {
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'mobile_number' => 'required|string|unique:users|min:11|max:11',
            ]);
        }else{
            /*VALIDATION IF USER HAVE DATA AND IGNORE CHECK MOBILE NUMBER*/
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'mobile_number' => 'required|string|min:11|max:11|unique:users,mobile_number,'.$user->mobile_number,
            ]);
        }

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response(['data' => $validator->errors()->all(), 'status' => $user->mobile_number], 200);
        }

        ...
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(['data' => $ex->getMessage(), 'status' => '5'], 200);
    }
}
```

unfortunately i get this error:

```
The mobile number has already been taken.
```

what happen in that and how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass the user id not the phone number :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'mobile_number' => 'required|string|min:11|max:11|unique:users,mobile_number,'.$user->id,
            ]);
```

Or you can use the laravel Rule class like this :

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'mobile_number' => [
        'required',mobile_number,
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```