# How to make an update in the Controller with a unique 'email' field in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, axios

I am trying to create an update of my CRUD of users, but I am passing in the "edit" view the value of the email within this input, now ... when I try to update I cannot do it because it has an email request unique: users.

I am passing the data in sight with vue & axios. the Backend is Laravel.

view edit:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email <span class="help"></span></label>
                        <input type="email" name="email"
                               class="form-control form-control-line" v-model="fillUser.email">
                    </div>
```

App.js

```
 editUser: function(user){
            this.fillUser.id = user.id;
            this.fillUser.name = user.name;
            this.fillUser.fLastName = user.fLastName;
            this.fillUser.sLastName = user.sLastName;
            this.fillUser.age = user.age;
            this.fillUser.email = user.email;
            this.fillUser.password = user.password;
            $('#edit').modal('show');
        },

        updateUser: function(id){
            // alert('Nada man');
            var url = 'users/' + id;
            axios.put(url, this.fillUser).then(response => {
                this.getUsers();
                this.fillUser = {'id' : '','name' : '','fLastName' : '','sLastName' : '','age' : '','email' : '','password' : ''};
                this.errors = [];
                $('#edit').modal('hide');
                toastr.success('Usuario actualizado con éxito');
            }).catch(error => {
                this.errors = error.response.data
            });
        },
```

controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'unique:users',
        ]);

        $usuario = User::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
        $usuario->name = $request->get('name');
        $usuario->fLastName = $request->get('fLastName');
        $usuario->sLastName = $request->get('sLastName');
        $usuario->age = $request->get('age');
        $usuario->email = $request->get('email');

//        Variables
        $contraseña = $request->get('password');

        //        Si la contraseña está seteada la actualiza, si no es así no deja llenarla de un campo vacío
        if(isset($contraseña))
        {
            $usuario->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
        }

        $usuario->save();
}
```

I want to know how to perform the update correctly, if the email field does not undergo changes that are not updated, if it undergoes changes than if it is updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How validate unique email out of the user that is updating it in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942367/how-validate-unique-email-out-of-the-user-that-is-updating-it-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send old_email hidden type

```
 if($request->get('email') != $request->get('old_email')){
   $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'unique:users',
        ]);
 }
```

Comment: thanks, using "old" it not fix, but i did this:

$usuario = User::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
$email = $request->get('email');

        if ($email != $usuario->email)
        {
            $this->validate($request,[
                'email' => 'unique:users',
            ]);
        }