# laravel 8: update user email with unique validtion throw an error

Tags: sql, laravel, validation, unique

here is my edit user post request validation rule

```
public function updateuser(Request $request) { 
   $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$request->userid,
           
        ],
        [
            'name.required' => 'please name',
            'email.required' => 'please enter email',
           *****************
        ]
    );
}
```

but when I try to update the user I got this error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'test3@mail.com' for key
> 'users.users_email_unique'

smile question already ask here but it's not solved my problem (may be I try with wrong way)

[1. How validate a unique email out of the user that is updating it in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942367/how-validate-unique-email-out-of-the-user-that-is-updating-it-in-laravel)

Comment: Is `$request->userid` set?

Comment: yep is set and i check with dd($request->userid)

Comment: I solved this problem alternative way always

Comment: Please share your code snippet used to update the user