# How to take User Id from Request(rules) for update?

Tags: laravel

Could I know how to take the user Id to Request an update? for example, when I updated the user and password. But, except email. At that time, It showed "the message that the email is already taken. When I searched for solutions, I found to solve with the user id.  I know this question is asked many times. But, I didn't get any suitable answer for me. Could you help me, please?

This is my Controller Code

```
public function edit(Users $request,$id){ 
    $users=User::whereId($id)->firstorFail();
    $users->name         = $request->get('name');
    $users->email        = $request->get('email');
    $users->password     = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
    $users->role         = $request->get('role');
    $users->update();
    $request->session()->forget('editvalue');
    $userdata = User::paginate(4);
    // session()->flash('status', 'User has been successfully added.');
    return view('pages.auth.register', compact('userdata'))->with('status','User has been successfully added.');
}
```

This is my Request Form. I want to take id value in this. When I take value, it is showing the message that Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'name'          => 'required', 'string', 'max:255',
        'email'         => 'sometimes','required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,'. $this->users->id,
        'password'      => 'required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed',
        'role'          => 'required', 'string',
    ];
}
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('users/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@editscreen');
Route::post('users/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@edit');
```

Comment: You forgot to add the email column in your `unique`rule

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How validate unique email out of the user that is updating it in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942367/how-validate-unique-email-out-of-the-user-that-is-updating-it-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't validate `{id}` in the request class but you can validate with regex in the route. (My Example is for laravel 8 but the principle remains the same)

```
Route::post('/users/edit/{id}', [UsersController::class, 'editscreen'])
        ->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also put the column name to the rule,
the pattern should be `unique:table,column,except_id`

Can you replace your RequestForm with this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'          => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email'         => ['sometimes','required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'. $this->users->id],
        'password'      => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'role'          => ['required', 'string'],
    ];
}  }
```

Comment: I did . But , It is showing the message that Trying to get property 'id' of non-object.

Comment: Probably the reason is you are not passing user with correct way, can you try changing your route from `Route::post('users/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@edit');` to
`Route::post('users/edit/{users}', 'UsersController@edit');`

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I got the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got with this.

```
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;//import Rule class 

    public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'          => 'required', 'string', 'max:255',
        'email'         => ['sometimes','required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id),
    ],
        'password'      => 'required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed',
        'role'          => 'required', 'string',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem and managed to solve by adding `$this->id` only.

```php
public function rules()
{
     return [
        'name'  => ['required', 'string', 'max:255']
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:users,email,' . $this->id]
    ];
}
```