# Laravel email validation create or update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have a platform where a user can buy stuff from a shop even if he is not a (registered user) and then before proceed to payment, I save his data. So I'm using this validation.

```
public function save_personal_info(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'first_name' => 'required|string|max:88',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|max:88',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'filled|alpha_num|min:8',
            'gender' => 'required|in:Male,Female',
            'confirm_password' => 'filled|same:password',
            'country' => 'required|string|max:88',
            'city' => 'required|string|max:88',
            'state' => 'required|string|max:88'
        ]
    );

    if (!$validator->fails()) {
        $exist = false;
        if (Auth::id()) {
            $user_id = Auth::id();
            $exist = true;
        }

        if ($exist) {
            $user = User::updateOrCreate(
                ['email' => $request->email],
                [
                    'first_name' => $request->first_name,
                    'phone' => $request->phone,
                    'last_name' => $request->last_name,
                    'email' => $request->email,
                    'country' => $request->country,
                    'city' => $request->city,
                    'state' => $request->state
                ]
            );
        } else {
            $user = User::updateOrCreate(
                ['email' => $request->email],
                [
                    'first_name' => $request->first_name,
                    'phone' => $request->phone,
                    'last_name' => $request->last_name,
                    'email' => $request->email,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                    'country' => $request->country,
                    'city' => $request->city,
                    'state' => $request->state
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

But if the user email already exists, I'm receiving an error, and I can't use:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'.$id,
```

Since no id is sent from the front end, how can I bypass the existing email without validation and return an error?

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942367/how-validate-unique-email-out-of-the-user-that-is-updating-it-in-laravel

Comment: @AmitChaudhary as i mention in my question that i don't sent user_id so i can't use $id

Answer (score 0):

'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',

Above line should be like this:

'email' => 'required|email',

Comment: This figure out  is only for validation error What You want.  If the email column in the user table is unique you may get another error . If you remove this error you should update email column attributes in database->migration definition

Comment: in this way i will have duplicate emails since it's not unique

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).