# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'where clause' in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application I have simple form to update some existing date.

following is my update method

```
public function update(Request $request, SalesManager $salesmanager){
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'full_name' => 'required|min:5',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:sales_managers,'.$salesmanager->id,
            'telephone' => 'required|max:10',
            'joined_date' => 'required|date',
            'current_route' => 'required',
            'comments' => 'max:256'
        ],[
            'full_name.required' =>'Full name is required.',
            'full_name.min'=> 'Full name should contain at least 5 minimum letters',
            'email.required'=>'Email is required',
            'email.email'=>'Invalid email format',
            'email.unique' =>'Email address is already exists',
            'telephone.required' => 'Telephone is required',
            'joined_date.required'=>'Joined date is required',
            'current_route.required'=>'Current route is required',
        ]);

        $salesmanager->update($validatedData);
        return redirect()->route('salesmanagers.index')
        ->with('success','Sales manager updated successfully');
    }
```

and following is my SalesManager model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class SalesManager extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        protected $fillable = [
            'full_name', 
            'email', 
            'telephone', 
            'joined_date', 
            'current_route', 
            'comments'
        ];
    }
```

But when I try to update data from the front end blade, I'm getting the following error....

***SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'where clause'***

[image]

[image]
I could not find any issue with my controller or model, since the all other methods are working well...

I'm using php 8 and laravel 9

Comment: salesmanager->id doesn't happen to be 3 in this case? Not sure why it's added to the email in the validated model, that's for someone with more Laravel knowledge to comment on :)

Comment: this is added after I get an error for the email field it already exists even though I was trying to update content... was that a wrong approach to avoid that issue? please correct me if I'm wrong and if you think that's the reason behind this issue.. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942367/how-validate-unique-email-out-of-the-user-that-is-updating-it-in-laravel

Comment: @ArcticFox the error is going to have a full stack trace, look who is trying to execute that code (what code from you is leading to that part, share the stack trace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular error is being thrown due to the `unique` rule of the `email` field in your validation. You're asking it to confirm the `email` doesn't exist but it's trying to compare the `email` against an `id` (in this case the `id` of your `$sales_manager` object).

Try replacing your `email` rule with the following:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:sales_managers,email,'.$salesmanager->id,
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel [**5.8+ the introduced `->ignore()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique) with object.

```
# syntax
Rule::unique('column')->ignore($object)
# code
Rule::unique('email')->ignore($salesmanager)
```